# unable to get list of webelements text box value using getText(); and getAttribute();

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have made List of stored **webelements**, in that list some of element will get text box value through get `getText();` and some will get through `getAttribute();`.here I made a for loop mentioning `getAttribute();` to that list of **webelement** and get **textbox** values of each **webelement**, but here I am getting `getAttribute();` text box values rest of elements which has `getText();` I am unable to get those **textbox** values.
Is there any IF condition which has to satisfy both methods i.e `gettext();` and `getAttribute();` and get **textbox** values ,if I use only method I am getting for that method text box values rest of elements showing **white spaces** and printing   HERE IS THE CONSOLE O/P **[null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSqkK.png)**.

```
    List<WebElement> e=new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    e.add(sign.empchequedatetext);
    e.addAll(sign.wagestlistvalues);
    e.addAll(sign.taxesvalue);
    e.addAll(sign.additionalincomelistvalues);
    e.addAll(sign.otherdeductionslistvalues);
    e.add(sign.netpayvalue);
    int calculatevaluessize= e.size();
    System.out.println("the total value size: "+calculatevaluessize);


    System.out.println("taxes size is: " + taxesvalues+"||"+wages+"||"+add+"||"+deduc);
    List<WebElement> emplist = s.getOptions();
    int empsize = emplist.size();
    System.out.println("emp size is: " + empsize);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < empsize; i++) {
            WebElement emp = emplist.get(i);
            emp.click();
            String empname = emp.getText();
            excel.setCellData(path, "Sheet2", i + 1, 0, empname);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            for (int j = 0; j < calculatevaluessize; j++) {
                WebElement taxesvalue = e.get(j);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                    String values = taxesvalue.getAttribute("value");
                    System.out.println("the calculate pay values are: "+values);
                    excel.setCellData(path, "Sheet2", i + 1, j + 1, values);

                }
```

plz mention any if condition in my second for loop,i have tried but what type of condition i have to place

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method to return one thing or the other:

```
private String getRowText(WebElement taxesvalue){
    if (taxesvalues.getText() == null){
        return taxesvalue.getAttribute("value");
    }
    return taxesvalues.getText();
}
```

This method should replace your `taxesvalue.getAttribute("value");`

Comment: Hi j.barrio,the above condition you mentioned is working getText(); for element containing, but not for getAttribute(); for the element containing it is showing white space in console

Comment: Could be other attribute, the one which contains the valid string? Could you share one getText working WebElement and one getAttribute WebElement?

Comment: in the above mentioned List i have stored webelements in those we can get either through gettext(); or getattribute(); individually i have tried for each element, since i made a List and for loop it is mandatory to mention if else condition which can either work out for each webelement for getText and getAttribute. if i use getText(); elements which has to get getattribute are coming with 'null' in console, and if i use getAttribute(); elements which has to get getText are coming with white space it has value in textbox but showing white space in console

Comment: Maybe the page has certain refresh while you are in the first loop. That's means, the null could be because the WebElement not the properties. Could you print the element before get the property?